# Is there a way to set multiple artists for one song?

Tags: itunes, macos

I have an album that contains many songs, some of which are performed by several artists.

I do want all the songs to appear under one album in the albums, and when I am browsing by artists, so under each artist I should see this album and the songs he participated.

1. How do I set more than one artist on a song?
2. How do I make it appear in the library the way I described above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this, you only have one artist field per track.

What you could do is listing the name of all artists in the artist field and then create smart playlists with rules for "Artist contains".

Comment: As @patrix correctly noted, iTunes does not allow this: the “Artist” metadata field is treated as one string, hence using separators like “/”, “,”, “&” or “feat.” will only make iTunes display an extra artist name including these. See this [Apple Support discussion thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3091571?start=0&tstart=0) for a recent take on the issue.

Comment: Use `;` separator to make multiple artist in one track.

Answer (score 2):

To add other artists, use `;` separator or `/` between artists. (`Artist1; Artist2; Artist3; Artist4` or `Artist1/Artist2/Artist3/Artist4`)

 I tried this in my iPod (Shuffle 3rd)

Example:

 I have "On The Floor" song. This song have 2 artists. It is Jennifer Lopez and Pitbull.

 On the artist field, type `Jennifer Lopez; Pitbull`. Then if you want to add a smart playlist contain Pitbull, use 'Artist contains' and fill the box with 'Pitbull'. Then it will show songs with Pitbull artist.

This is the example:
[image]

on the image above, *on the floor* is listed with my other Pitbull songs but still shows the other artist (Jennifer Lopez)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set "Album Artist” to whatever artist you want to use.  Then it’ll group like you want it.  You get to “Album Artist” from GetInfo -> Info

Answer (score 2):

instead of using (artist; artist) or (artist/artist) you can also simply use (artist & artist) but it still doesn't fully do what you want it to do.